Lang How does commutative diagram show category?
This is from p.57 on the 3rd Edition of Lang's Algebra published by Springer.

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a category.  We may take the morphisms of $\mathfrak{A}$ as the objects of a new category $\mathfrak{C}$.  If $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $f':A'\rightarrow B'$ are two morphisms in $\mathfrak{A}$ (and thus objects of $\mathfrak{C}$), then we define a morphism $f\rightarrow f'$ (in $\mathfrak{C}$) to be a pair of morphisms $(\varphi,\psi)$ in $\mathfrak{A}$ making the following diagram commutative


He then states that from this it should be clear that $\mathfrak{C}$ is a category.  I can verify that

The first category axiom is verified by setting up another morphism
$(\Phi,\Psi)$ mapping the morphisms $F:\alpha\rightarrow\beta$ to
$F':\alpha'\rightarrow\beta'$, and observing that
the only way $(\Phi,\Psi)$ is in both $\text{Mor}(f,f')$ and
$\text{Mor}(F,F')$ is that if $\alpha=A,\beta=B$ and so forth
The identity axiom is satisfied when $\varphi=I_A$ and $\psi=I_B$ where $I$ denotes the identity in $A,B$ respectively.
The associativity of the morphisms is the one I'm not sure how to really verify.  Do I just stack three commutative diagrams on top of each other, then note the resulting diagram is also commutative (hence the order not mattering)?

In any case, how does he come to this conclusion so quickly?  Is this just a standard commutative diagram for categories?  This is only four pages after he defined what a category was!  It also seems as though most of this "proof" is just based on observation, so I feel as though I've completely missed the point of this example.

Associativity is the idea that it doesn't matter how you "stack three diagrams". It basically boils down to the associativity of composing the morphisms on the left and right sides of the diagrams.

I am not sure what you are asking exactly, but yes this is a pretty obvious example of a category. It is known as the arrow category of $\mathfrak{C}$, and you can see it as the functor category $[\mathbf{2}, \mathfrak{C}]$, where $\mathbf{2}$ is the "walking arrow" category with two objects and a single arrow between them.

@IsAdisplayName and that associativity follows immediately from how morphisms behave under the category axioms?

@Redcrazyguy associativity is part of the definition of a category

@IsAdisplayName I thought the final category axiom was the associativity of the morphisms?  That's what I'm referencing when I say the associativity follow from the category axioms.

Suppose you have $(\phi , \psi) : f \to g$ , $(\phi', \psi') : g \to h$ and $(\phi'' , \psi'') : h \to k$. Associativity is then checking that
$$(\phi'' , \psi'') \circ ((\phi' , \psi') \circ (\phi , \psi)) = ((\phi'' , \psi'') \circ (\phi ' , \psi')) \circ (\phi , \psi)$$
Based on the definition of composition in this category, $(\phi' , \psi') \circ (\phi , \psi) = (\phi' \circ \phi , \psi' \circ \phi)$. Thus the above equation simplifies to
$$(\phi'' \circ (\phi' \circ \phi) , \psi'' \circ (\psi' \circ \psi)) = ((\psi'' \circ \psi') \circ \psi , \(\phi'' \circ \phi') \circ \phi)$$
this should just boil down to checking that
$$ \phi'' \circ (\phi' \circ \phi) = (\phi'' \circ \phi') \circ \phi$$
and likewise for $\psi$. Thus, we don't really need to look at a diagram. We just have to think about what we're actually being asked to do and think about how composition is defined.
Why does Lang skip over this? Well, authors often like to skip writing out boring and somewhat trivial proofs. Checking that something forms a category often meets those conditions. If this proof currently seems mysterious, thats okay. Spend more time looking at examples and thinking about the definition of a category. I bet that not too long from now, you'll look at this and think, "oh, that was easy."

so is the commutative diagram actually used in the proof?  It seems as though it's not used to show any of the category axioms.  Also, what should I take away from the diagram (this is what I meant by "is it a standard commutative diagram"), i.e. what should I look out for in this diagram so I can look at a different commutative diagram and immediately go "aha, this is clearly a category"?

The commutative diagram is part of the definition of the morphisms in the arrow category.

@NaïmFavier but I've seen that square commutative diagram a lot of times previously, are you saying as long as two morphisms are related by a pair of morphisms $(\varphi,\psi)$ then $(\varphi,\psi)$ forms a category?

I'm not saying anything like that. That doesn't make any sense.

@Redcrazyguy I think a lot of your questions stem from some confusion around the basics of "what is a category?" I haven't read Lang's Algebra, but it may not be the best intro to categories. Try reading just section 1.1 of Riehl's "Category Theory in Context", you can find a free pdf on her website.

@IsAdisplayName is category theory where commutative diagrams are usually introduced?  I think my confusion is to what they are used for.  They seem intuitive as to the morphisms they represent, but they seem more like a statement than any kind of reasoning tool (i.e. this is how the morphisms relate to each other).  I think I kind of understand the three category axioms, but I think you would probably know better.

@IsAdisplayName I will also check that book out thanks!

@IsAdisplayName I think I can restate my original question as this:  I can easily verify that $\mathfrak{C}$ is a category just from the 3 axioms of category theory (without reference to the commutative diagram), what does the commutative diagram add/do here?
